# How do I merge two Pandas Dataframes based on the closest value in one column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have two data frames in Pandas in Python that I am trying to merge together based on a column that gives a time, but the value is somewhat different in the two data frames.

They look something like this:

```
    file    ftime
0   file1   2021-10-21
1   file2   2022-04-09
2   file3   2022-11-17

    file    utime       ident   origin
0   file1   2021-10-22  4       se
1   file2   2022-05-01  6       fi
2   file3   2022-11-19  8       no
```

What I want to do is merge the frames on the value in 'file' and the values in 'ftime' in the first frame and 'utime' in the second frame, but as you can see, the times will be somewhat different. I was hoping to get it so that the rows merge if the value in 'utime' is within 3 days after the corresponding value in 'ftime'. For the example, it would mean that the first and last rows would merge, but the middle one would not. The result should then be:

```
    file    ftime       utime       ident   origin
0   file1   2021-10-21  2021-10-22  4       se
1   file2   2022-04-09  NaN         NaN     NaN
2   file3   2022-11-17  2022-11-19  8       no
```

If the times were equal, it would be easy to merge with the following code, but since I need to apply a timespan, I'm not sure how to do it. Any help is really appreciated!

```
data_1 = {'file': ['file1', 'file2', 'file3'], 'ftime': ['2021-10-21', '2022-04-09', '2022-11-17']}
data_2 = {'file': ['file1', 'file2', 'file3'], 'utime': ['2021-10-22', '2022-05-01', '2022-11-19'],
          'ident': [4, 6, 8], 'origin': ['se', 'fi', 'no']}

df_ver = pd.DataFrame(data = data_1)
df_stat = pd.DataFrame(data = data_2)

df_new = pd.merge(df_ver, df_stat, left_on = ['file', 'ftime'], right_on = ['file', 'utime'])
```

Comment: Use `merge_asof`